# Use 'LookAt' to look at GameObject but only on the x-z plane

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class tankGunLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Vehicle;

    private Vector3 target = new Vector3(Vehicle.transform.x, 0, Vehicle.transform.z);

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Vehicle != null)
        {
            transform.LookAt(target);
        } 
    }
}
```

ERROR: Assets\Scripts\tankGunLook.cs(9,66): error CS0236: A field initializer cannot reference the non-static field, method, or property 'tankGunLook.Vehicle'

I don't quite understand what is not working here, I want the Tank Gun to look at the player or vehicle and but I don't want it to move on the y-axis. So I used 'Vehicle.transform.x' to get the x position but I guess it isn't actually getting it?

Then I want to get the y-position of the Tank Gun itself so it stays stationary but when I do this

[image]

ERROR: Assets\Scripts\tankGunLook.cs(9,45): error CS0027: Keyword 'this' is not available in the current context

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class tankGunLook : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject Vehicle;

    

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 target = new Vector3(Vehicle.transform.position.x, transform.position.y, Vehicle.transform.position.z);
        transform.LookAt(target);
    }
}
```

I fixed it. I'm not sure how but I assume it's something regarding the fact that the x, y and z positions are constantly updating so they need to be put in the updating section.